# USB Y cable to gain more power and quick charge 2.0

Tags: usb, power, cable

sorry, i don't know anything about electrics.

if i use USB Y cable, 5 Volt 2 A and 5 V 2 A, then is output 5 V 4 A? (increase in current only?)

if so, if i hookup this to 2 each ports(two 5v 2a) and use [this product](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B013NNQJ14), will quick charge work?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few parts to this question -

- Many ports are 0.5 amp - a Y cable can combine them to 1 amp.  (Assuming
  the same voltage and a cable with parallel connections you can double the
  current)
- If you have a Y cable and plug it in to ports capable of 2 amps each, the
  amperage that can be pulled through it could be 4 amps BUT
- Quickcharging is negotiated between the host and slave, but a Y port will not allow for negotiating of the higher current.

It is unclear what this device does, but if I'm reading it correctly it may work, but it would most likely be ignoring current limiters on ports and using it could damage your host devices if plugged into USB ports which do not allow drawing of 2.4 amps.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to realize QC in most efficient way? actually im trying to use it on 21w anker solar charger.(it has 2 ports 2.4a max) in review video, current is little unstable depending on weather and its avg output is about 1.6a

Comment: This is not a question for this stack exchange, but the answer is you can't safely (for more then a short period and from the POV of damaging electronics) pull more wattage then the source. Depending on your usage case you may be able to hook a battery up as a buffer and/or use a solar concentrator / tracker to get more power - but really you need a bigger solar panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use this QC adapter with some dumb source of 5V power (as a solar charger) with sufficient current capacity (> 2.4A), then yes, it will enable QC aware devices to draw more than 500 mA with their cables. The adapter relies on unofficial rating of USB ports, which usually can supply much more current than the minimum required by specifications. But the usual caveats should apply regarding connector contacts limitations, so the Y-cable might help a bit.

However, it looks like this QC adapter provides only the basic, 5-V charging level. As such, your combo (solar plus the QC adapter) won't be optimal for real QC-enabled phones, who might request 9V or 12V levels. But it is better than nothing (I mean than the USB default 500mA).